# Trying to remove all values from column J that are not also in column F in Excel

Tags: excel

Now I figure there's a fairly easy way to do this in Excel. I was going to write a custom Python way to do this, but I'm not extremely versed in the CSV module. I don't know VBA at all (though I'm not adverse to learning it for this task).

Basically my issue is this:

I have a column J with multiple names in it (concatenated first and last names from columns H and I with the formula `=H&" "&I`, and I want to do a few things:

1 - First I want to associate column G with column J. (Column G contains a contact id that I am trying to associate with all of the other rows). I believe I would do this with a group?

2 - Second, I want to remove all values of J (and likewise G) that do not have a match in the entire F column.

Essentially, for all values of F, if there is no equal in the J column to any of them, I want that grouping of J and G removed or hidden.

Note, absolutely no validation is being done on G during this entire time, only between F and J.

**My suspicion is that this would mean comparing each value of J to an array of the values of F, and then if there is no value that corresponds, deleting the group that that particular value of J is a part of.**

EDIT: To clarify, the data in F is also first and last names.

Comment: Hello Andrew, are you entirely averse to a Python solution? If you are familiar with Python then the CSV module is actually not all that bad :) Happy to help work through a solution. In any case, could you provide a few sample rows to get a good idea of how it is set up?

Comment: I've actually started working on a solution in Python. This is what I've got so far:

import csv

F = csv.reader(open('F.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=',')
FList = []
for row in F:
    FList.append(', '.join(row))

JG = csv.reader(open('JG.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=',')

ultralist = []

for item in FList:
    for row in JG:
        if row[1] == item:
            ultralist.append(row)

print ultralist

Comment: Nice! So the general concept of csv.reader is that it will read the contents of each row in the CSV into a list where each element represents a column value. Alternatively, there is csv.DictReader which lets you access the columns by name. Happy to go into chat if you want to work through a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I understand this is horrendously inelegant (and probably even totally uneccessary) but this will do what you want. You just need to adjust the ranges for your columns to whatever you want(I used 17,000 rows). I used columns J and F like you said so you should just have to run it:

```
Sub CheckColumnForValuesInAnotherColumn()

Dim CheckColumn As Range
Dim ColumnToDeleteValuesFrom As Range

Dim wbk As Workbook
Set wbk = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wbk.Sheets(1)

Set CheckColumn = ws.Range("F2:F17000")
Set ColumnToDeleteValuesFrom = ws.Range("J2:J17000")

Dim cell As Range

On Error Resume Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ws.Select

    For Each cell In ColumnToDeleteValuesFrom

        If Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cell.Value, CheckColumn, 1, False) = IsError(xlErrNA) Then
            cell.ClearContents
        End If

    Next cell

ws.Select
Range("A1").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Good Luck.

Comment: This is for VBA btw. You would need to insert this code into a vba module and then run it.